# What are the threats of using hashing functions that are built into the DBMS? (besides man-in-the-middle attacks)

Tags: hash, databases

There are functions like `MD5` and `SHA2` in MySQL which can be used to hash values before putting them into the database, or when searching over values.

As I proposed a possible solution in a comment to [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/269991/292322) to a question, I was told that providing unhashed values to a database is unsafe as an attacker can have access to the database. While I do understand that one could read the data that is *already* in the tables (it's quite obvious), I fail to understand how could they catch the plain data provided to a request by just having access to the database, since the plaintext is never saved, it's hashed *before* being put to the database.

I've tried to Google the possible ways for an attacker to do that and did not find anything. Another way to reveal the plaintext is a man-in-the-middle kind of attack, which is prevented by using SSL I believe. So the question is if it's possible if an attacker only has access to the database.

Comment: It seems that person that wrote the answer that you linked is under the impression that you are trying to build a 'zero access' system, where the server is untrusted and therefore should have zero access to the user's secrets.  Is that the case?  If so, then `insert into tblNotes (f1dNote) values (sha2('usersecret'))` is problematic, because the DBMS sees the user's secret when this query is submitted.  A rogue server admin (or attacker that has gained access to the server) could capture the user's secret at that point in time.

Comment: @mti2935 well, currently I use a virtual hosting from a rather trusted provider, and all the operations are conducted within this server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Database systems can have query logs which contain the sensitive data as plaintext, since the hashing takes place *after* the query has been processed. Given sufficient privileges, the log can be enabled from the MySQL console while the database system is running. MySQL also supports [plugins which make it possible to examine queries before they're executed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/extending-mysql/8.0/en/plugin-types.html#query-rewrite-plugin-type). This again could give an attacker access to the initial data before hashing.

But even more importantly: None of the basic hash algorithms like MD5 or SHA-2 are suitable for protecting the confidentiality of data, except for very special cases (namely when you're dealing with purely random data which cannot realistically be recovered through a brute-force attack against the hashes).